# Sharepoint online client webpart accesses Azure SQL data

Tags: azure-sql-database, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to create a Sharepoint online webpart. My problem: I'm new at Sharepoint developing...

If I understand the concepts correct, I have to create a client webpart. But how can I access my data in the Azure SQL. Please could someone post some related links for me... My own search at Google was not realy successful...

Thanks
vocaris

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Business Connectivity Services (BCS) and Secure Store. BCS connects SharePoint solutions to external data, and Secure Store enables user authentication for the data. By using an External List, you can display the contents of a table from SQL Azure in SharePoint Online. Users can read, edit, and update the data, all in SharePoint Online. For more information, please read [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-an-External-List-from-a-SQL-Azure-table-with-Business-Connectivity-Services-and-Secure-Store-466f3809-fde7-41f2-87f7-77d9fdadfc95).